# O que está errado com minha Thread ultilizando synchronized - Java

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Começei a estudar tread vi alguns exemplos do java7 e do java8 ultilizando lambda, cheguei em uma parte para ultiliza o synchronized que e para deixar tipo uma lista de espera de threads onde a proxima e executada após uma terminar, estou testando mas não estou conseguindo fazer rodar a multithreading o que estou fazendo de errado? a saida do código deveria ser primeiramente a T1 depois a T2 e por final a T3 mas ele numca segue o resultado de quando terminar uma ir para a próxima.

```
    public class mainThread {

        public synchronized void imprimirValores(String numeroThread) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                System.out.println(numeroThread + " : " + i);

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new Thread(() -> {

                new mainThread().imprimirValores("T1");

            }).start();

            new Thread(() -> {

                new mainThread().imprimirValores("T2");

            }).start();

            new Thread(() -> {

                new mainThread().imprimirValores("T3");

            }).start();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você criou uma sincronização de instancia, já que seu método `imprimirValores()` é um método de instancia. Sendo assim, a sincronização vai funcionar apenas para objetos ou métodos daquela instancia que está acessando o método sincronizado.

No seu método `main()` você criou 3 threads e cada uma delas com uma instancia diferente. Sendo assim, o método `imprimirValores()` não vai sincronizar as 3 threads como uma unica instancia, mas sim uma instancia para cada thread e seus valores não serão impressos ordenadamente.

Para que funcione como você quer, teria que ter uma única instancia que faz a chamada ao método sincronizado, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainThread mt = new MainThread();

    new Thread(() -> {

        mt.imprimirValores("T1");

    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {

        mt.imprimirValores("T2");

    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {

        mt.imprimirValores("T3");

    }).start();

}
```

Observe que desta vez, temos apenas uma única instancia acessando o método sincronizado, desta forma, a sincronização vai funcionar. Mas pode acontecer de não existir uma ordem em qual thread será executada primeiro. Algumas vezes pode ser a T1, T2, e T3 outras vezes T1, T3, T2 ou T2, T1, T3. Mas os valores estarão ordenados, porém a JVM é quem vai decidir qual das 3 threads ela executa primeiro.

Comment: Achei que sua resposta pecava na diversidade de solução para o problema, portanto fiz o contraponto focando apenas nesse ponto. De resto, ela está muito boa.

Comment: Obrigado teste aqui e funcionou o livro que eu estava lendo não tinha quase nada de explicação apenas falou para usar a palavra synchronized

Answer (score 1):

Não vou me delongar muito porque creio que a [resposta do @romarcio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246169/64969) explica muito bem. Só gostaria de deixar outras alternativas.

### Método de classe

No lugar de prender o método à instância, poder-se-ia prender o método à classe como um todo. O método em si não usa nada da variável de instância, então ele já poderia ser estático desde a sua criação:

```
public static synchronized void imprimirValores(String numeroThread) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    System.out.println(numeroThread + " : " + i);
}
```

Se por acaso necessitasse acessar alguma informação do objeto e mesmo assim se insistisse em ser um método da classe, poder-se-ia passar a classe como parâmetro:

```
public static synchronized void imprimirValores(mainThread selfObj, String numeroThread) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    System.out.println(numeroThread + " : " + i);
}
```

No meu exemplo, as propriedades do objeto estão acessíveis através do parâmetro `selfObj`.

### Objeto de trava de classe

Outra alternativa fácil e simples é a existência de um objeto sobre o qual se pode fazer a trava desejada. Esse objeto precisa ser único para toda trava que ele servir. Como queremos servir como trava aqui o método em toda chamada, independente de instância, vou definir que o objeto de trava é um campo estático de `mainThread`, pois esse é o seu local mais óbvio.

```
public class mainThread {
  private static final Lock lck = new Lock();
  public static synchronized void imprimirValores(String numeroThread) {
    synchronized (lck) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        System.out.println(numeroThread + " : " + i);
    }
  }
  [... o resto do código ...]
```

O bloco `synchronized` permite que você faça a trava sobre um objeto, podendo portanto essa mesma trava ser usada em diversos pontos do seu código.

Eu usei o objeto do tipo `Lock` por purismo. Se não me engano Java permite usar qualquer objeto como sendo pivô do `synchronized`.

Comment: Obrigado, realmente existe uma diversidade na solução, nem tinha visto essa função da trava (Lock).